# Using glmnet to predict a continuous variable in a dataset

Tags: r, model, prediction, glmnet, lasso-regression

I have this data set.
[wbh](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MKiwTNQiUqlidbJwKURvFL2NmqYJHYYg)

I wanted to use the R package glmnet to determine which predictors would be useful in predicting fertility. However, I have been unable to do so, most likely due to not having a full understanding of the package. The fertility variable is SP.DYN.TFRT.IN. I want to see which predictors in the data set give the most predictive power for fertility. I wanted to use LASSO or ridge regression to shrink the number of coefficients, and I know this package can do that. I'm just having some trouble implementing it.

I know there are no code snippets which I apologize for but I am rather lost on how I would code this out.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example on how to run glmnet:

```
library(glmnet)
library(tidyverse)
```

df is the data set your provided.

select y variable:

```
y <- df$SP.DYN.TFRT.IN
```

select numerical variables:

```
df %>%
  select(-SP.DYN.TFRT.IN, -region, -country.code) %>%
  as.matrix() -> x
```

select factor variables and convert to dummy variables:

```
df %>%
  select(region, country.code) %>%
  model.matrix( ~ .-1, .) -> x_train
```

run model(s), several parameters here can be tweaked I suggest checking the [documentation](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/Glmnet_Vignette.pdf). Here I just run 5-fold cross validation to determine the best lambda

```
cv_fit <- cv.glmnet(x, y, nfolds = 5) #just with numeric variables

cv_fit_2 <- cv.glmnet(cbind(x ,x_train), y, nfolds = 5) #both factor and numeric variables

par(mfrow = c(2,1))
plot(cv_fit)
plot(cv_fit_2)
```

[image]

best lambda:

```
cv_fit$lambda[which.min(cv_fit$cvm)]
```

coefficients at best lambda

```
coef(cv_fit, s = cv_fit$lambda[which.min(cv_fit$cvm)])
```

equivalent to:

```
coef(cv_fit, s = "lambda.min")
```

after running `coef(cv_fit, s = "lambda.min")` all features with `-` in the resulting table are dropped from the model. This situation corresponds to the left lambda depicted with the left vertical dashed line on the plots.
I suggest reading the linked documentation - elastic nets are quite easy to grasp if you know a bit of linear regression and the package is quite intuitive. I also suggest reading [ISLR](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/), at least the part with L1 / L2 regularization. and these videos: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2ij6eaaSl0), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZAM5OXrktY), [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S06JpVoNaA0) [4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSKzqb0EKS0), [5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5I1G1MfUmA), [6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMKVUstjXBE), first three are about estimating model performance via test error and the last three are about the question at hand. This [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1REe3qSotx8) is how to implement these models in R. By the way these guys on the videos invented LASSO and made glment.

Also check the [glmnetUtils](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnetUtils/index.html) library which provides a formula interface and other nice things like in built mixing parameter (alpha) selection. Here is the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnetUtils/vignettes/intro.html).

Comment: That makes sense thank you. Just wondering, but how would I use this to reduce and eliminate predictors using glmnet?