# get coefficients of cross-validated glmnet model in caret

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

How do I get coefficients of cross-validated glmnet model in R's caret package?

```
library(caret)
x = matrix(rnorm(500), ncol=10)
y = rnorm(100)
control = trainControl(
         method="LOOCV",
         allowParallel = TRUE,
         number = nrow(sample_df), 
         verboseIter = FALSE,
         returnData = FALSE
        )

  my_elasticnet <- train(x, y,
                     method = "glmnet",
                     preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                     trControl = control)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract the coefficients for the best tuning parameters in caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079660/extract-the-coefficients-for-the-best-tuning-parameters-in-caret)

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732633/extract-data-from-glmnet-output-data/47733577#47733577)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to show the code for sample_df. However, assuming the following you can access it as follows:

```
library(caret)
x = matrix(rnorm(500), ncol=10)
y = rnorm(100)
sample_df = cbind.data.frame(y,x)
control = trainControl(
  method="LOOCV",
  allowParallel = TRUE,
  number = nrow(sample_df), 
  verboseIter = FALSE,
  returnData = FALSE
)

my_elasticnet <- train(sample_df[2:11], sample_df$y,
                       method = "glmnet",
                       preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                       trControl = control)

my_elasticnet$finalModel$beta
```

If you just look at names, you'll get everything you need regarding the final model:

```
> names(my_elasticnet$finalModel)
 [1] "a0"          "beta"        "df"          "dim"         "lambda"      "dev.ratio"   "nulldev"    
 [8] "npasses"     "jerr"        "offset"      "call"        "nobs"        "lambdaOpt"   "xNames"     
[15] "problemType" "tuneValue"   "obsLevels"   "param"
```

**EDIT: In Response to comment**

The final model depends what level of alpha and lambda you select. There are 66 such such parameters. If you want to choose the one the machine *thinks* is best, you can do:

`coef(my_elasticnet$finalModel, my_elasticnet$bestTune$lambda)`

That will give you just a 11x1 vector that you're looking for.

Comment: my_elasticnet$finalModel$beta gives me 10 x 62 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix". I want the coefficients used to fit the final model.

Comment: @FissehaBerhane: see my addition.